# Is there a way to make a 'transient' parent container in HTML that is automatically scales to the same size as its child?

Tags: html, css

So I have the following problem.

Say I have a `LayoutDiv` that states all my content on my website should be a max of 1280px.

I also have 2 ChildDivs, FixedChildDiv & ScaledChildDiv.

`FixedChildDiv` knows exactly what size it should be, which is 300px.

`ScaledChildDiv` does know know what size it should be. It just knows that it should keep stretching to the maximum content width its parent allows.

So:

```
<LayoutDiv style={{width: 1280px}}>
  <FixedChildDiv style={{width: 300px}}/>
  <ScaledChildDiv style={{width: 100%}}/> 
</LayoutDiv>
```

Now I want to wrap both `FixedChildDiv` and `ScaledChildDiv` with a 'transient' container to add an `onClick` attribute to it. That is a container that has no layout properties and simply takes on the exact same size as the child.

I can't use a normal `div`, because it will expand to 100% width by default, and it will end up having a larger container area than `FixedChildDiv`.

If I try to use `div inline:block`, it will not expand fully, but for `ScaledChildDiv` it will end up taking the minimum possible width as `width: 100%` no longer fill up the entire width of the LayoutDiv.

I've experimented and realized that if I used an anchor `<a/>` tag, it does what I want it to do. `<a/>` will automatically take up the same size as both `FixedChildDiv` and `ScaledChildDiv`, while being 'transient' and making the `width:100%` still apply to the main `LayoutDiv`.

However I don't think I should be using an `<a/>` tag for everything as it means something. Is there some property I can add to a `<div/>` to make it behave the same way? Or is there some other tag that I can use that has similar properties?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the existing outer div to listen for the click?

Comment: Yes. The outer div might contain several different children. `ScaledChildDiv` and `FixChildDiv` might have different event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flex blox to reach that behavior and JS to add an event listener on the click to the main div.

```js
$('.LayoutDiv').click(function(e){$('.alert').html('you clicked on the divs');setTimeout("$('.alert').html('');",1000);})
```

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:1200px;
  color:white;
}
.FixedChildDiv {
  width:300px;
  flex-grow:0;
}
.ScaledChildDiv {
  flex-grow:1;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="LayoutDiv" style="background-color:black;">
  <div class="FixedChildDiv" style="background-color:red;">
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  content inside fixed child<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="ScaledChildDiv" style="background-color:blue;">
    content inside scaled child
  </div>
</div>
<p class="alert"></p>
```